# Compiling C++11 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code, g++

I'm using Visual Studio Code to compile C++ programs and it works for most C++ programs as it compiles it using `g++` command. However, I am facing difficulty in compiling `c++11` programs using it.

When I try compiling C++11 programs, the compiler command `g++` tries to compile it using default C++98 Standard and this results in errors.

I am aware that using `g++ -std=c++11`, we can compile C++11 programs using `g++` and it works fine when I use it in my `cmd` as:

> g++ -std=c++11 some_program.cpp

I wish I could tweak some setting in Visual Studio Code and change the compiler command from `g++` to `g++ -std=c++11` so that I could compile programs by just hitting the `run code` button. However, I'm not able to find one. Please help me out if there are alternate ways to get my program compiled.

Currently, I'm getting errors as:

> some_program.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> some_program.cpp:12:33: error: in C++98 'A' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
>   vector A = { 11,2,3,14 };

The snippets are correct and have been tested with online compilers using C++11. Here, it is trying to compile using `C++98` as seen in the error.

Comment: VS Code does not compile nor run your programs. G++ compiler compiles and links your source, your CPU runs the code. VS Code is just an editor.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Go to `Settings` > `User Settings`
In here, search for `Run Code Configuration`:

Under this menu, find:
`"code-runner.executorMap"`

Edit this Setting by adding it to User Setting as below for C++11 support:

```
"code-runner.executorMap":{
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++11 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
},
```

OR

Edit this Setting by adding it to User Setting as below for C++17 support:

```
"code-runner.executorMap":{
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
},
```

Hope this helps !